# C++: Getting a Segmentation Fault when I run my Program (inputting numbers from a file into arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, fstream

I'm trying to input numbers from a text file. What I need to do is sort the numbers into an array that stores odd numbers, as well as one that stores even ones. From there, I just need to output the average, total, min, max, and then the numbers in the array that are greater than the average.

From researching, it's my understanding that a seg. fault occurs because of problems with memory allocation. I checked my arrays, and I don't think there should be a problem. The total amount of numbers in the file is 50, and so there should be room for the numbers, with what I allocated for my arrays in the beginning of main.

Here is my input file:

46  30  82  90  56  17  95  16  48  26
4   58  0   78  92  60  12  21  63  47
19  41  90  85  14  -9  52  71  79  16
80  51  95  102 34  10  79  95  61  92
89  88  66  64  92  63  66  64  39  5

I am using Linux, by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void oddOrEven(int [], int [], int [], ifstream &, int &, int &, int &);
void calcData(int [], int [], double &, double &, double &, double &, double &, int &, 
int &);

int main()
{

int i;
int a;
int b;
double totalEven = 0;
double totalOdd;
double average = 0;
double max = 0;
double min = 0;
int array[75] = {0};
int evenArray[50] = {0};
int oddArray[50] = {0};

ifstream fileIn;

fileIn.open("file.txt");

if (!fileIn){
cout << "\nError, could not open file.\n";
}

oddOrEven(array, evenArray, oddArray, fileIn, i, a, b);

calcData(evenArray, oddArray, totalEven, totalOdd, average, min, max, a, b);

fileIn.close();

return 0;

}

void oddOrEven(int array[], int evenArray[], int oddArray[], ifstream & fileIn, int & i, 
int & a, int & b){

while (fileIn >> i) {

fileIn>>array[i];

if (array[i] % 2 == 0){
evenArray[a]=array[i];
a++;
}

else{

oddArray[b] = array[i];
b++;

}}}

void calcData(int evenArray[], int oddArray[], double & totalEven, double & totalOdd,  
double & average, double & min, double & max, int & a, int & b){

//Find min, max, total and average for Even Array.

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){

totalEven += evenArray[i];

if (i = 0){
min = evenArray[i];
max = evenArray[i];
}

if (evenArray[i] < min)
min = evenArray[i];

if (evenArray[i] > max)
max = evenArray[i];

}

average = totalEven/a;

cout << "\nMinimum is " << min;
cout << "\nMaximum is " << max;
cout << "\nTotal is " << min;
cout << "\nAverage is " << average;

//Numbers higher than the average for Even Array:

for (int k = 0; k < a; k++){
if (evenArray[k] > average/2)
cout << evenArray[k] << " ";
}

//Find min, max, total and average for Odd Array.

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){

totalOdd += oddArray[i];

if (i = 0){
min = oddArray[i];
max = oddArray[i];
}

if (oddArray[i] < min)
min = oddArray[i];

if (oddArray[i] > max)
max = oddArray[i];

}

average = totalOdd/b;

cout << "\nMinimum is " << min;
cout << "\nMaximum is " << max;
cout << "\nTotal is " << min;
cout << "\nAverage is " << average;

//Numbers higher than the average for Odd Array:

for (int k = 0; k < b; k++){
if (oddArray[k] > average/2)
cout << oddArray[k] << " ";}
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code?

Comment: Have you tried it using `std::vector<int>` instead of arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You use `i`, `a` and `b` to index into your arrays, but you never initialize them.

Also, the `if (i = 0)` should read `if (i == 0)` (a single `=` is assignment, not comparison).

I didn't read the code all that closely. There are probably other errors.

A couple of general recommendations:

1. When your code crashes, run it in a debugger. This will pinpoint the location of the crash, and will let you examine the state of the program. This is often enough to understand the root cause of the problem.
2. Use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Ok, I got it now...Thanks. It took me a minute to see what I was dong wrong. I thought that just because I declared a, b and i and passed them by reference, that "that" was good enough, but you are correct. Needed to just initialize them to zero in the start of that function.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why this happens, and why passing by reference is not good enough, even if it is declared to zero. I know that adding i = 0, a = 0, b = 0; at the start of the "OddOrEven" function fixes my problem, but not why it doesn't do the same thing when I pass them into my function, without declaring them.